# Highlight Build Output Panel of Sublime Text 2

Tags: build, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

How do I highlight the error lines in the Build Output Panel of Sublime Text 2?
I have some lines in the output like this:

```
This is just a message
Warning: <C:\Path\File.ext:12> WarningMessage ORANGE
Error  : <C:\Path\File.ext:34> ErrorMessage RED
```

How do I colour the Error and Warning lines?
I have setup my custom .sublime-build "file_regex" key to detect them for doubleclick, but don't see how to style the matches.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `.sublime-build` file?

Comment: I don't believe the build output panel can be colorized...

Comment: From the screenshot in this package documentation, it seem possible:
https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests#usage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible. It takes a bit of work, but I have done it at least on Linux.

#### Step 1

Copy the Packages/Default/exec.py to your User directory (or the Plugin directory if you are building a plugin). I changed the name of the .py file to correlate with the Build file, but I do not think this is strictly necessary.

#### Step 2

Change the run method of the ExecCommand class to call your syntax file and color scheme. I added these around line 117 in the current build, just above the line that has:

```
self.output_view.settings().set("result_file_regex", file_regex)
```

I added in the following lines.

```
self.output_view.settings().set("color_scheme", "Packages/Color/Color.tmTheme")
self.output_view.set_syntax_file("Packages/Scheme/Scheme.tmLanguage")
```

Where `Packages/Color/Color.tmTheme` is the color scheme definition file you are seeking and where `Packages/Sheme/Scheme.tmLanguage` is the syntax definition file you are wanting to integrate.

#### Step 3

Update your `.sublime-build` file to call the custom file you modified above with the following call:

```
"target":      ["Packages", "User", "NewExecFile.py"]
```

*Note*: The following will not work:

```
"target":      ["Packages/User/NewExecFile.py"]
```

unless you were to update the NewExecFile.py to call the `target` field without joining with file separators.

I'm on Linux, so you'd obviously need to update for windows. But it is working like a charm for me. I now have a build function which returns results that match the color scheme I use for development.

References:

- [Sublime Unofficial Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)
- [Sublime Forum Question](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12648)

Comment: Thanks. In Sublime Text 3 it is as easy as adding a "syntax" key to the .sublime-build file with a path to a .tmLanguage file